# Database Design for Video-DB with Playlists

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

It has been a while since my last database class and I have a few questions about the following basic database design for a PHP/MySQL application that is a **video database with playlists**:

```
t_playlists
p_id (PK) | name | description

t_videos
v_id (PK) | name | description | playcount

t_mapping
v_id (FK) | p_id (FK)
```

**The queries I want to perform are as follows:**

- Get all playlists - including the number of videos in each playlist, but not the videos themselves
- Given a `p_id`, get all videos in that playlist
- Given a `v_id`, get the playlist that this video belongs to

Currently, one video can only belong to one playlist.

**Now to my questions:**

1. Could you remind me of why we use a mapping table in such a case? I recall that it's "good practice", but I don't recall exactly why. How is using a separate mapping table "better" than including the `p_id` as another column (FK) in `t_videos`? Wouldn't that make my queries a lot simpler?
2. Is there a more efficient design that achieves the same?
3. What are the SQL queries for the three cases I have described? (I am using MySQL)

Comment: For question 1, ask yourself if you want a video to be added to only 1 playlist ever or to more than 1 playlist and you'll have your answer.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I remember. So if I want `1` video to be added to `n` playlists, then I must use the mapping table, right!? How much of a difference does it make in terms of efficiency whether or not I use the mapping table? I am thinking one playlist would be enough if it greatly improves the efficiency of the queries!?

Comment: It's called a junction table usually and I don't really see how you can add 1 video to n playlists otherwise. In terms of efficiency, if 1 video = 1 playlist, it's quicker than 1 video = n playlists because you do only 1 lookup for 1 video.

Comment: An alternative to the mapping table would be: If I know that `1` video belongs to say `3` playlists *at max*, then I can create 3 additional FK columns in `t_videos`. Would that or would that not be more efficient than using a mapping table?

Comment: No, you should never have 3 different columns for foreign key aiming to the same table.

Comment: Not really. But what do you consider efficient? What you'd manage to do is use the db in a completely wrong way. If it'd be more efficient at say 1 billion rows - it's hard to say. But if you don't plan on having billions of videos and playlists, I wouldn't even consider "smart" and "efficient" (and wrong) uses of a database.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you currently have a One to Many relationship between videos and playlists then there is no need to the mapping table just have the p_id (FK) in the t_videos. If you were to have a Many to Many relationship then you would need the mapping table. You are right since in your case you have a One to Many, having the p_id in the t_videos table would make the query simpler.
2. Like I said, unless you have a many to many there is no need for the mapping table. As for a more efficient design, the concept you have is very simple and so is the design. Not really sure if it could get more efficient than that.

3.The first one needs a nested statement to get a count of the videos so it would go something like.

```
SELECT "name", description, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_videos WHERE fk_p_id = p_id) AS VideoCount FROM t_playlists
```

That will display the count for each playlist in a column called VideoCount

```
SELECT * FROM t_videos WHERE fk_p_id = given_p_id
```

(This is if you were to drop the mappings table and include the p_id in the videos table

```
SELECT * FROM t_playlists 
INNER JOIN t_videos
ON t_playlists.p_id = t_videos.fk_p_id 
WHERE v_id = given_v_id
```

Note that I put * instead of the column names for simplicity, but you should include the column names that you want to display only.

**EDIT:**  This is all assuming you have a one to many which is what you stated. It seems to me that the relationship should be many to many though.